# array must be intialized with brace enclosed intializer

Tags: arrays, class, templates, arduino, structure

```
 template <typename t> struct my_params { std::array<t,2> mass = 
  {0,0}; };

  int main(){
      my_params<float> mp; mp.mass[0]=0.888;
  }
```

For the above code, I am getting error as "array must be initialized with brace enclosed intializer". The code runs fine on code block but when I tried to run on Arduino ide,  it simply gives an error. I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this `my_params <float> mp[] ;`

Comment: Could you please update your answer to describe why it should be changed to that ?